# dopen(): "failed to map segment from shared object" when not running as root

Tags: c++, linux, dlopen

I am trying to load some self-written libraries under a self-made Yocto Linux.

It works fine when running the same program as root, but not as another, later added user.

```
for (<all files found in directory>)
{
    m_HModule = dlopen(Filename.c_str(), RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);

    if (m_HModule == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", dlerror());
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Loaded module " << Filename << endl;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, my version of dlerror() does not return too terribly precise information:

```
Loaded module /opt/epic/libepicGpioToggle.so
Loaded module /opt/epic/libepicSaveImage.so
Error: libboost_filesystem.so.1.66.0: failed to map segment from shared object
Loaded module /opt/epic/libepicFpgaCommunicatorUserDemo.so
Error: /opt/epic/libepicCommunicatorFpga.so: failed to map segment from shared object
Error: /opt/epic/libepicDataproviderTimedData.so: failed to map segment from shared object
Error: /opt/epic/libepicDataproviderFromCamera.so: failed to map segment from shared object
Loaded module /opt/epic/libepicFramework.so
Error: /opt/epic/libepicTriggerMonitor.so: failed to map segment from shared object
Error: /opt/epic/libepicTemplate.so: failed to map segment from shared object
```

Even with maximum file permissions `chmod 777 *` and all libraries being owned by the calling user, it does not work.
Everything works fine when running as root or via sudo.

Yes, some of these libraries use boost elements, which are all available unter /lib and accessible by the calling user. If I do not try to load the libraries referencing boost, the other failures persist.

It is always the same libraries failing to load; the order does not seem to matter.
The compiler settings for all of my libraries look the same, and are all abbreviated from the same "template project".

I checked the dependencies with `ldd`, `straced` all system calls and do not see any difference, apart from the error messages.

The user's shell environment `env` is the same as for root.

With `export LD_DEBUG=files`, I see

```
      4231: file=/opt/epic/libepicSaveImage.so [0];  dynamically loaded by ./libepicFramework.so [0]
      4231: file=/opt/epic/libepicSaveImage.so [0];  generating link map
      4231:   dynamic: 0x0000ffff8b56fd60  base: 0x0000ffff8b524000   size: 0x000000000004d608
      4231:     entry: 0x0000ffff8b5487a0  phdr: 0x0000ffff8b524040  phnum:                  7
      4231: 
      4231: 
      4231: file=/opt/epic/libepicGpioToggle.so [0];  needed by /opt/epic/libepicSaveImage.so [0] (relocation dependency)
      4231: 
      4231: 
      4231: calling init: /opt/epic/libepicSaveImage.so
      4231: 
      4231: opening file=/opt/epic/libepicSaveImage.so [0]; direct_opencount=1
      4231: 
Loaded module /opt/epic/libepicSaveImage.s
```

for successful loadings, but

```
      4231: file=/opt/epic/libepicCommunicatorFpga.so [0];  dynamically loaded by ./libepicFramework.so [0]
      4231: file=/opt/epic/libepicCommunicatorFpga.so [0];  generating link map
Error: /opt/epic/libepicCommunicatorFpga.so: failed to map segment from shared object
```

for failures.

User limits `ulimits -a` look the same for both root and user:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 10974
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 10974
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

I increased `max locked memory` to 100's of MB, but no change.

What could be different from the user's perspective?

Comment: Ordinary users may have limits on various details of how much memory they may use, which typically are not enforced on privileged processes.  If one or more of your shared libraries requires a lot of memory then that could be the issue.  That would not necessarily require the library files to be large on disk.  If this is the issue then the `ulimit -a` command might clue you in.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Yes I tried that, and the output looks exact the same, no matter if running as root or user.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: I've searched for two days around that issue, here on stackoverflow and of course on google. Nothing seems to provide any help on how to get more detailed information about the general error code. Most topics are like "program x does not run" - "then try THIS or upgrade it" - "okay, now it works again", but are not as low-level as dlopen().

Comment: Does `LD_DEBUG=all` provide additional clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JohnBollinger was right - it was the user's limits, with 16384 kbytes being too small for "max memory size".

I had to increase the limit in `/etc/security/limits.conf` for the specific user by adding

```
username soft memlock unlimited
username hard memlock unlimited
```

and then configuring SSHD to obey these limits by adding

```
session    required     pam_limits.so
```

to `/etc/pam.d/sshd`.

Being root ignores all set limits, no matter if logged on through SSH, directly or via RS-232 TTY.

Thanks for pointing me into the right direction!